# How to pass an attribute value from ImageButton to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

On page load I add a new attribute (UploadStatus) to an ImageButton (FileUpload_result) from code behind. Now on button click I want to retrieve the value of the added attribute. How can I do that?

```
public string UploadStatus = "testing";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { FileUpload_result.Attributes.Add("UploadStatus", UploadStatus); }


<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="FileUpload_result" OnClick="FileUpload_Click" ImageUrl="icon-ok.png" UploadStatus="testing" /> 

protected void FileUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // How can I get the value of the added attribute UploadStatus? The value is testing in this case}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FileUpload_Click method you can access the attribute like this.

```
((ImageButton)sender).Attributes["UploadStatus"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like FileUpload_result.Attributes[""UploadStatus"] might get it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c%28v=vs.140%29.aspx